# What does `shortTitle` do in `contributes.commands`?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When developing a VSCode extension, I found this `shortTitle` property under `contributes.commands`, I tried setting it, but couldn't find where it's shown, does anyone know?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a new feature in baking so you can track its progress on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/126457).

To quote its purposes from [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34048#issuecomment-862192315),

> This doesn't mean that there is no need for a short name and long name
> but it must be on the command, not the menu. With that menu implements
> decide what property to use, e.g already today the command palette
> menu uses the title and category property whereas other menus only use
> the title property.
>
> In fact, internally we added support for shortTitle which complements
> title

Answer (score 0):

The description of `shortTitle` has been updated in [this commit](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/132695d42ddde8dd6968507ce6429eb916110424):

> (Optional) Short title by which the command is represented in the UI. Menus pick either `title` or `shortTitle` depending on the context in which they show commands.

Comment: Any idea how to tell a (sub)menu to use the `shortTitle`?